# Applying a particular sort case for a content type only

Tags: search

I'm using ApacheSolr (Solr 4.0) with Drupal 7. I'm implementing search on 8 content types, and I need to alter Solr functionality for a specific content type, Articles. In articles, there are 2 fields: *Category* (textfield) and *Weight* (integer). The *Weight* field exists in all content types, while the *Category* field exists only for articles. I have altered ApacheSolr query to change the sort order so the result is first sorted ascending by *Weight* field and then by relevancy.

This was done using `hook_apachesolr_query_alter()` and the following code.

```
$query->addParam('sort', 'weight');
$query->addParam('sort', 'score');
```

Now I want either one of two solutions, when user searches a string.

Only Articles content type should be sorted in the following order.

#### SOLUTION 1

1. First according to if string exists in category field and a term reference field
2. Then according to weight field
3. Then according to relevancy

#### SOLUTION 2

1. First according to if string exists in category field and a term reference field
2. Then according to weight field
3. All other fields shouldn't be taken in consideration(means they should be omitted) except the above 3 fields

I want to implement either of the above solutions. But can't figure out any method for implementation.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! So far, you stated facts, without asking any explicit question. What don't you understand about the solutions you described? Keep in mind that if the question is really "How do I implement one of the solutions?" that is too broad for us; if you are asking which solution you should adopt, we cannot take a decision for you.